# What are the wildcard characters present in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

In ORACLE what are the wildcard characters present I want to know ? I have been seeing this tutorial from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) and they have listed Wildcard Characters in **MS Access** and Wildcard Characters in **SQL Server**.

What about ORACLE?

I have checked [ORACLE DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/title.htm) but there are no wildcard characters present.

If there are wildcard characters present then :

1: What are the equivalent wildcard characters of (^ , #, !) present in ORACLE?

2: How can I use them in **ORACLE** syntax?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '[!bsp]%';
```

What should be the oracle equivalent text of the above code using wildcard ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking about "wildcard characters" in comparing text strings (as opposed to, for example, the asterisk used in `select * from ...`). If so: Oracle has the `LIKE` operator, where the **only** wildcard characters are percent and underscore, and `REGEXP_LIKE` (and other regular expression functions) where the wildcard characters are the same as in the POSIX extended regular expression standard.

Comment: I am new to oracle . I am trying to know what are the equivalent of these wild card characters  (  !  , ^, # ) @mathguy

Comment: I am asking about the whole list of every wildcard characters that i can use in Oracle other than percent and underscore ? where can i get it ? I have searched their **Documentation** but to no avail. I am new to ORACLE and never used REGEXP_LIKE.

Comment: You are missing the point.  There is no such thing as an overall list of "wildcard characters in Oracle'.  Just like mathguy tried to explain, it depends on what context these wild cards are being used in.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas - At least in Oracle (I don't know about other languages), wildcard characters depend on the condition or function you are using. The wildcard characters for `LIKE` are documented with the `LIKE` condition, and they are only the underscore and the percent. For regular expressions, the much longer list is documented, for example, here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix002.htm#SQLRF55542

Comment: @SaumyojitDas: " I am trying to know what are the equivalent of these wild card characters ( ! , ^, # ) " - there aren't any. In Oracle you must use the regular expression functions such as `REGEXP_LIKE`, `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, etc. [Documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1003)

Comment: @BobJarvis - not true. You can also use wildcards with `LIKE` - the list is just very limited. I already said that twice (in my answer and in a Comment) - did you miss that, or are you saying that's not true?

Comment: @EdStevens  then tell me how i will write the (**SQL statements select all customers with a City NOT starting with "b", "s", or  "p"**) in ORACLE.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas - It seems that **that** is your actual question. The answer is simple:  `where substr(city, 1, 1) not in ('b', 's', 'p')` (assuming you really want to exclude **lower**-case letters, which is quite odd; but you get the idea). Note that no wild card is needed for this.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas - then you must use regular expressions. The condition will use `REGEXP_LIKE` rather than `LIKE`. Other than that, read the documentation to learn more about regular expressions; Oracle doesn't use a proprietary system, it uses the most broad **standard**. In your specific case: `where regexp_like(city, '^[^bsp]')`. I can explain each part of the regular expression, but this site is not for lectures on generalities like "regular expressions", it is for specific questions.

Comment: YES i want to use wildcard characters. This means they are present  and can be used with regexp not like .  WHAT  is this **^** stand for ?is it a wildcard character?

Comment: @SaumyojitDas - I already gave you the link to the documentation. Don't be lazy!

Comment: @mathguy why i got -2 downvote.whats wrong in my question?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution for the same query in Oracle SQL;
Problem Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-6/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen
**Question:** Query the list of CITY names starting with vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, or u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates.
**Solution:**

*SELECT DISTINCT(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (CITY,'^(A|E|I|O|U).*') ;*

Here's the link where I found a relevant solution.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm